# PHP Interpreter/Compiler

Tags: php, compiler-construction, interpreter

I am trying to understand how the php compiler/interpretor works.

I tried to download the php source code and tried to understand how it works. I was not able to find proper documentation. WOuld be great if someone could throw light on th modules that make the php compiler and also how the apache server uses the php compiler..

Comment: Well, Apache can communicate with PHP a number of ways, the most common being mod_php and FastCGI.  Do you have experience with compilers/interpreters?  If not, then I doubt you'll be able to just dive in and understand one as complicated as this.

Comment: You'll want to start by studying the basics of compilers/interpreters (parsers, lexical analyzers, tokens, etc...).

Comment: @ webbiedave
Thanks.. I want to understand the control flow and not the way the php code is compiled. Hope I am clear. I want to understand as Xiong says the way the apache uses php compiler. Were do i get started??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As webbiedave said you might want to study the basics of compilers/interpreters. You can find most of the parser and lexer stuff in the files Zend/zend_language_scanner.l and Zend/zend_language_parser.y

If you want to get a feeling of how php works I suggest you set breakpoints at the beginning of `zend_execute_scripts()` in Zend\zend.c and at the line

```
if ((ret = EX(opline)->handler(execute_data TSRMLS_CC)) > 0)
```

in the file Zend\zend_vm_execute.h and then step through the code.